# Create a binary numeric array table

Tags: python, pandas

Given pd.DataFrame with numeric values. I created a row that is summarized each column, I would like to convert it to binary values 0 /1 if the number is larger or less than 0.1 percent of the column amount.

[dataframe example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QXTSZ.png)
the last row is the sum of the column (the dataframe is large, its just a part of it)

I know that I need a loop for each row and column.
I manged to do it in R:

```
percent <- vector(length=nrow(df))
for (i in 1:ncol(df)) {
     percent[i] <- sum(df[, i])*0.001    
 }
df_bin <- df
for (i in 1:33) {
     for (j in 1:nrow(df_bin)) {
         if (df[j,i] >= percent[i]) df_bin[j,i] = 1
         if (df[j,i] < percent[i]) df_bin[j,i] = 0
     }    
 }
```

But how do I do it in python? I am new...

Tnx :)

Comment: kindly share the result of ur R dataframe. as data, not pics

Comment: see the example. I want to convert the numbers. if the number is grater then 0.1% of the amount than write 1, if smaller write 0. I know how to write a loop in R, but not in python...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply call `df.sum(axis='rows')` to get the sum over the rows, multiply that by `*0.001` and then compare that to the original dataframe (this is done through broadcasting) to get the result in booleans. And you can change the bool to a 0/1 by casting it to `int`

```
df_bin = df > df.sum(axis='rows')*0.001
df_bin = df_bin.astype(int)
```